# system command in R and escaping issue

Tags: r, linux, null, system

I am trying to clean some embedded null characters is a csv file using this command below

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' datafile.csv
```

This command works fine when i run this directly on a linux terminal. However when I try to execute this via R using system command like this below

```
system(" 'tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' datafile.csv' ")
```

i get an error,

```
sh: tr -cd : command not found
: command not found
```

I suspect this is something related to escaping some stings, need help resolving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the extra pair of single quotes that messes things up.
This worked on my end, see if you can make it work.

```
system("printf '\11 eleven \12 \13 fifty-eight \15 \
        55 \40 \150 \176 \n one, two three\n' > so-test.txt")
system("cat so-test.txt")
system("tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < so-test.txt > so-test2.txt")
system("diff test.txt test2.txt")
```

PS: **always** include a reproducible example when asking questions like this. I don't know if my example makes sense, I think your method of removing null characters looks a little strange.

Comment: the first option `system("printf '\11 eleven \12 \13 fifty-eight \15 \
        55 \40 \150 \176 \n one, two three\n' > so-test.txt")` resulted in an empty file. the third option `system("tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < so-test.txt > so-test2.txt")` worked. I had to change my file from CSV to TXT. Thanks for the suggestions.